# Is this a correct way to solve this high school coordinate geometry question?

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, analytic-geometry, triangles, pythagorean-triples

Here's the question:

> Given point $A$: $(-3;-1)$
>   Given point $B$: $(3;7)$
>
> Given point $Z$: $(x;0)$
>
> Find the $x$ coordinate of point $Z$ so that the angle of view of AB segment is $90$ degrees at point Z, so Point Z has a $90$ degrees interior angle.
>
> The answer is $4$ and $-4$.

Here's the way I did it, is it correct?

- $AB$ segment has length of $10$.
- So to make $ABZ$ a right triangle, one method we can use is that $AZ$ segment and $BZ$ segment must have the length of $\sqrt{50}$, because then $\sqrt{50}^2 + \sqrt{50}^2 = 10^2$. (Which is the length of $AB$)
- So in that case triangle $ABZ$ would be an isosceles right angled triangle and indeed there would be a $90$ degrees interior angle at point $Z$.
- Then, I used distance formula to calculate the $x$ coordinate of point $Z$ so that $AZ$ and $BZ$ segments would have a length of $\sqrt{50}$.

So that's how I got $4$ and $-4$, and these are the correct answers.

I know there are many possible solutions to solve this problem, but is my method correct?

Comment: Consider formatting with MathJax. Here is a tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @M47145 I edited. Could you please now take a look and tell me if my method is correct? I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: sorry i meant segments, i edited. is it clearer now? and the question asked for an 45 degrees interior angle at point Z in the ABZ triangle

Comment: what do you mean is not enough?

Comment: @user2547460 I would roll back the last edit, [angle of view of a line segment](http://planetmath.org/angleofviewofalinesegment) is a perfectly understandable thing.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the 
[angle of view of a line segment](http://planetmath.org/angleofviewofalinesegment) are two arcs and Z are on these arc and also it is on a line, that is the $y=0$ line. Your task is to figure out the formula for the arcs and then find the intersections of $y=0$ on it. Edit: hint, you need to use the [Central Angle Theorem](http://www.mathopenref.com/arccentralangletheorem.html) to find the centre of the arc/circle.

I do not understand why $ABZ$ is a right triangle in the first place.

You claim

> So to make $ABZ$ a right triangle, one method we can use is that $AZ$ segment and $BZ$ segment must have the length of $\sqrt{50}$, because then $\sqrt{50}^2 + \sqrt{50}^2 = 10^2$. (Which is the length of $AB$)

This is wrong. If AZ and BZ equal length and the angle at Z is 45 degrees then the other two angles of triangle is (180-45)/2.

Comment: but if we assume that ABZ is a right triangle then would my method be correct?

Comment: the question said that the  angle of view of a AB segment at point Z is a right angle so ABZ must be a right angled triangle

Comment: *BLINK* what? The question says the angle of views is 45 degrees! Do you know what a right angle in degrees is? I edited my answer with a hint on how to solve this.

Comment: omg, I'am really sorry, i'm an idiot, I didn't copy the question correctly. So to make everything clear, the question said that the angle of views is 90 degrees so that would make ABZ triangle a right angled triangle. again sorry, it's 1am here...

Comment: Pity, it's much more interesting with 45 degrees :)

Comment: so now that we cleared the confusion, can you tell me if my method is correct?

Comment: I'm giving your answer plus one for that

Comment: Nope. You *still* need the central angle theorem, the set of Z where AZB is 90 degrees is a circle with the central point being the halving point of AB. Then you need the formula for the circle and intersect it with the line. Because you assume AZ=ZB, why?

Comment: I can't explain why AZ=ZB, but if you look at the answer and use distance formula then AZ has the same length as BZ.

Comment: I will give you a new problem where Z is (x,1). Now what? Just because some dumb luck makes the solution AZ=BZ does not mean you can just presume that. Indeed, if Z is on (x,1) then AZ!=BZ. Or move A to (-3, -2) or...

Comment: Okay. Anyway, the answer sheet says i get partial credits for my answer if I solved the question using the AB segment/AB diameter. Do you think I would get this partial credit?

Comment: While I was given a math teacher masters so long ago you probably were not yet born, I am not your teacher indeed I have not stood in front of a class in this *century* so I have no idea what do they do these days. I wouldn't but ... what do I know?

Comment: Okay and how did you become so good at maths? I've never been excellent at maths but neither relatively terrible either, even though I practice a lot, and I am incredibly fond of maths I still struggle with it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40145/discussion-between-chx-and-user2547460).

Answer (score 1):

your method is correct. Good job sorry it took so long,  it's hard to review things not in math Jax I highly recommend you learn

Comment: note x^2+y^2=z^2 iff x and y are legs to a right triangle with hypotenuse length z.

Comment: Thank you. I know it's technically correct because I do indeed end up with the correct answer but is it mathematically correct too? The official answer to this question used the thales theorem, another answer used scalar vector multiplication method.

Comment: as I said your method is correct not just your answer. you may want to include a note about the x^2+y^2=z^2 iff right triangle thing to make it more rigorous

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect

First of all,

$Z(x, 0)$
Now for every possible value of x, a line can be made that is intersecting line AB at $45 $ degree.

i think you mean point $A$ and $B$ is seen at $45$ degrees.

i got the answer this way.

$m_1$ = $\frac{7+1}{3+3}$

$m_1$ = $\frac{4}{3}$

$tan 45$ = $\frac{-m_1 + m_2}{1 + m_1*m_2}$

$1 + m_1*m_2$ = ${ + m_2 -m_1}$

$1 + \frac{4}{3}*m_2$ = ${+m_2 -\frac{4}{3}}$

$3 + 4*m_2$ = ${-4 + 3*m_2}$

$m_2$ = ${-7}$

$m_2$ = $-7$

$\frac{7-y}{3-x}$ = $-7$

$7x +y -28$ = $0$

Now it is given that y = $0$

$7x - 28 $ = $0$

$x$ = $+4$

Do the same for $A$.

Comment: Thanks, the answer sheet says i get partial credits for my answer if I solved the question using the AB segment/AB diameter. Do you think I would get this partial credit?

Comment: @user2547460 Maybe not because if you use that then the answer would come by a slightly different way. not very different but just slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

So all the fuzz here resulted from some unsharp definitons (where is the angle, what angle).

[image: the sitation]

You can try out different $x$ values [here](http://ggbm.at/Km6bjQxC).

Comment: thank you, but i know my answer is correct, i was asking if my method was correct to calculate the correct answer :)